# Scrollable sidebar, not always present, with breakpoints variable width

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

I need a dynamic sidebar (not always present) with a variable width (percentage) based on screen breakpoints.

I need this sidebar to be scrollable so I used `position: fixed`.

#### PROBLEM

In the below REPL the sidebar (when present) is positioning itself above the main content.

#### QUESTIONS

- How can I address the problem?
- For the `.main` class I'm using `flex-grow: 1`. Am I wrong?
- Is there a web resource with these layouts explained?

#### REPL

https://codepen.io/fredhors/pen/abvQJWr

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to add a class on the container and add a `padding-left` to it when the sidebar is visible.

Since the sidebar is visible by default add already the class `sidebar-open`.

The HTML will update as follow:

```
<div class="container sidebar-open">
```

The CSS will update as follow:

```
.sidebar-open {
  padding-left: 16.666667%;
}
```

and add `left: 0;` to the `.sidebar`

You JS will be like this:

```
function myFunction() {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");
  var text = document.getElementById("sidebar");
  var container = document.querySelector(".container");
  if (checkBox.checked == true){
    text.style.display = "block";
  } else {
     text.style.display = "none";
  }
  container.classList.toggle("sidebar-open");
}
```

**EDIT**

If you cannot use JS, you can try moving from `position: fixed;` to `position: sticky;`

The CSS will be:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
}


.sidebar {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 16.666667%;
  position: sticky;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  background-color: red;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Here's the updated working [Codepen](https://codepen.io/alezuc/pen/gOaQWPv)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is there no way to achieve the same goal without `padding-left`, "simply" using flexbox?

Comment: @FredHors I cannot think about reaching that now with "pure flexbox", but since you already have the JS to handle the click on the checkbox I find it a pretty clean solution.

Comment: This Javascript is fake. It's REPL only.

Comment: @FredHors check if position:sticky; is what you're looking for! Answer and Codepen updated!

Comment: @FredHors don't forget to accept the answer if it helped. Thanks :)